# How to modify an NSMutableDictionary using setValue or setObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

In the header file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *vocabs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *vocab;
```

in the .m file:

```
-(void) loadFile {
    NSString* filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"vocabs" ofType:@"json"];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

    vocabs = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];



}

-(void) renderVocabs {
    //NSLog(@"json file = %@", vocabs);
    if ([vocabs count] == 0) {

    } else {

        vocab =  [vocabs objectAtIndex:vocabIndex];
        //NSLog(@"%d", vocabIndex);
        //NSLog(@"%d", [vocabs count]);
        NSString *word = [vocab objectForKey:@"word"];

        labelWord.text = word;

        tvDefinitions.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@" , [vocab objectForKey:@"subject"], [vocab objectForKey:@"definitions"]];

        NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",word];
        NSLog(@"%@", imgName);
        [imageVocab setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:imgName]];

        NSString *remembered = [vocab objectForKey:@"remembered"];

        if ([remembered isEqualToString:@"0"]) {

            self.btnRemember.hidden = FALSE;

        } else {

            self.btnRemember.hidden = TRUE;

        }

    [self setDisplayFontSize];

    }
}
- (IBAction)btnTick:(UIButton *)sender {
    [vocab setObject:@"1" forKey:@"remembered"];
}
```

and I got

```
** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** First throw call stack:
```

What did I do wrong? Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is clear. `vocab` is really an `NSDictionary`, not `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: show how you initialise vocab , probably there you only have an immutable `NSDictionary`

Comment: You need to show how you are creating the dictionary

Comment: Just added how to create the NSArray.

Comment: That doesn't show vocab though

Comment: `vocab` is probably an index of of the `vocabs` array.

Comment: cool I've added the vocab there

Comment: Send `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` options to your JSON serialization call. You should get mutable containers back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array *most likely* contains only `NSDictionary` instances, not `NSMutableDictionary` instances, therefore you can't modify them. If you send `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` to your `JSONObjectWithDataCall` you should get back mutable objects.

```
self.vocabs = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that *calling* something an NSMutableDictionary (or array) doesn't *make* it one.

Basically this code is irrelevant:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *vocabs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *vocab;
```

What matters is *what object you assigned to those properties*.

Comment: would that be casting issue?

Comment: It would be a creation/intstantiation issue. How are you creating `vocab`?

Answer (score 1):

This line...

```
vocab =  [vocabs objectAtIndex:vocabIndex];
```

Needs to be...

```
self.vocab = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[vocabs objectAtIndex:vocabIndex]];
```

Comment: I prefer @aaron answer though